# JS Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to add dynamically information from an XML and add to an div. My idea is to add the new div inside the existing div (not mandatory.. i can also actually add to the existing div)

**JS**

```
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");  //new Div
    newDiv.appendChild(sideTab);
    var existingDiv = document.getElementById("vertical");  //Existing div
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv,existingDiv);
```

sideTab will have something like that:

```
 <ul class ="tab" >
     <li><a href="#" class="tab"> Something</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Existing div

```
    <div class="left" id="vertical">
```

But when i execute i get this error:
Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: Where have you defined `sideTab`?

Comment: seems like whatever you have in `sideTab` variable is not of type `Node`, just what the error message says.

Comment: Speculation: `sideTab`'s value is a string (of HTML)

Comment: sideTab is filled inside a loop (is a very large method). Here is the info i get on the debug with the variable sideTab:   <ul class ="tab" >
     <li><a href="#" class="tab"> Something</a></li>
 </ul>

Comment: Then the error message very clearly explains what is wrong.

Comment: here is the definition of sideTab :    var sideTab = "<ul class =\"tab\" >";   after that i get all the li and href and it ends with sideTab += "</ul>"

Comment: @Joseph — So it is a string and not a node. It needs to be a node. See `createElement` and friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the string to DOM and add the element you want into the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); //new Div
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var el = parser.parseFromString(`<ul id="sideBar"><li><a>Something</a></li></ul>`, "text/html");
    var element = el.getElementById("sideBar");
    newDiv.appendChild(element);
    var existingDiv = document.getElementById("vertical"); //Existing div
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, existingDiv);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="left" id="vertical"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Fixed to work with string element.

[Plunker has been fixed.](http://plnkr.co/edit/x4SpbiHQ5LYKbY61brV2?p=preview)

Comment: The OP clarified, in the comments, that `sideTab` is a string and not `null`.

Comment: Just fixed. Please, don't downvote when the OP clarified in comments. I just didn't see it when I was creating the solution.

Comment: I still get the same error. "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: Did you test the plunker? I tested with FF and Chrome and it's working

Comment: my mistake, worked!, thank you and please dont downvote the comment